# Проблема при слияние строк

Tags: java, алгоритм

Тестирую кусок кода

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strArray = {"111", "222", "333", "444", "555"};
        String strTmp1 = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++){
            String strTmp = strArray[i];
            strTmp1 = strTmp1 + " " + strTmp;
        }
        System.out.println(strTmp1);
    }   
}
```

на выходе

```
null 111 222 333 444 555
```

Как убрать **null**

Comment: Написал вопрос и ответ сам собой пришел 
null меняет просто на ""

Comment: Погугли для самообразования такую вещь, как StringBuilder. Каждый `+` со строками создает в памяти новую строку, поэтому в реальной жизни твой код мягко говоря не совсем хорош. StringBuilder позволяет составлять строки избегая этой проблемы.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Решение данной задачи через `StringBuilder` - позволяет избежать замусоривание памяти из-за сложения строк (при сложении строк в памяти каждый раз создается новая строка). Поэтому, любое неоднократное сложение строк лучше производить через `StringBuilder`.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strArray = {"111", "222", "333", "444", "555"};
        StringBuilder strTmp = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++){
            strTmp.append(' ');
            strTmp.append(strArray[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(strTmp.toString());
    }   
}
```

Comment: Сложение строк использует `StringBuilder`, как минимум с Java 7. Но для цикла все равно эффективнее использовать `StringBuilder` явно.

Answer (score 1):

Отсеять нулевой вариант в цикле

```
        strTmp1 = ((strTmp1 == null)?"":strTmp1 )  + " " + strTmp;
```

При первом заходе в цикл у тебя strTmp1  =  null, поэтому появляется такое значение, а к нему же идёт + 1, + 2 и т д.

Или как вариант 2, присвоить в strTmp1  первое значение массива, а за тем сделать цикл с 1 до конца.

Comment: За что же минусы?

Comment: Видимо, за то, что `strTmp1` можно присвоить пустую строку при объявлении и тем самым сильно упростить код. P.S. Лично я минусов не ставил. Наоборот, поставил плюс. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Можно создать `ArrayList` и не мучаться, как вариант.

Comment: И как `ArrayList` поможет в данном случае?

Comment: При удалении будет присваиваться не 'null', а первая строка в массиве просто удалится.

Comment: Никто ведь ничего не удаляет. Проблема в том, что строка инициализирована `null` вместо `""`, и использование `ArrayList` вместо массива от этого никак не спасет.